# Perl equivalent to htmlentities()

Tags: php, perl, html-escape-characters

I am new to Perl.

I am trying to duplicate some/most of the functionality of PHP's [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

So far I have this:

```
$str = '" \' < >';

$str = join('&lt;', split('<', $str));
$str = join('&gt;', split('>', $str));
$str = join('&quot;', split('"', $str));
$str = join('&#039;', split("'", $str));

print $str;
```

It is working for my needs but the micro-optimizer in me just feels like there must be a better way.

I am terrible with regex and so many Perl tutorials deal with custom or non-standard libraries or it just seems this way due to my inexperience.

`perl -v` produces:

> v5.10.1

Comment: Instead of "the micro-optimizer in me just feels like there must be a better way", consider: "the [virtuously] lazy programmer in me wishes to avoid reinventing the wheel". Strive to find and use other/existing methods that have been written correctly.

Comment: @user2864740 Thank you for the sentiment but I certainly did try to find the proper existing method for quite some time, and there is certainly a plethora of information, but I was unsuccessful. Asking on SO is usually my final resort for all issues I have.

Comment: Make sure SO is not the first resort: https://www.google.com/webhp?q=perl%20html%20encode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [HTML::Entities](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML::Entities)'s `encode_entities`. (It obviously won't be 100% equivalent since the beavhour of `htmlentities` varies based on the arguments passed to it.)

Comment: Hmm, I could have sworn that this is a solution which I tried and received server errors but I literally started Perl yesterday so the error was probably in some other section of code. Anyways, this solution works for me and is error-free. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hey what you asked for can be achieved by using decode_entities()

Example code:-

```
use HTML::Entities; my $html = "Hey &amp; &lt"; print decode_entities($html), "\n";
```

Use this as a reference :- [Reference](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/HTML-Parser-3.72/lib/HTML/Entities.pm)

Comment: That's the inverse of what the OP asked for

Comment: Since the above answer already mentioned about encoding, i have edited my answer to decode so user knows both !  see above my answer was edited .

Comment: Good Perl examples seem to be a hit or miss so I would like to allow this answer for future Googlers :-) +1

Comment: Thats the spirit that develops us !. Peace